# Multiply Two colums in an array and find their sum

Tags: php, mysql

I have this array structure (see below) grouped by date from a database query, and I wish to  find the total for each group by multiplying the `quantity` by the `transamount`.

This is what i have so far:

```
    array (size=3)
    '2017-7-03' =>
            array (size=3)
            0 =>
                    array (size=4)
                    'paydate' => string '2017-7-03' (length=9)
                    'tariff' => string 'batch1' (length=31)
                    'quantity' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
                    'transamount' => string '20.0000' (length=7)
            1 =>
                    array (size=4)
                    'paydate' => string '2017-7-03' (length=9)
                    'tariff' => string 'Eye Test' (length=8)
                    'quantity' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
                    'transamount' => string '5.0000' (length=6)
            2 =>
                    array (size=4)
                    'paydate' => string '2017-7-03' (length=9)
                    'tariff' => string 'hub photos' (length=16)
                    'quantity' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
                    'transamount' => string '82.0000' (length=7)
                    '2017-7-04' =>
            array (size=9)
            0 =>
                    array (size=4)
                    'paydate' => string '2017-7-04' (length=9)
                    'tariff' => string ' Register' (length=21)
                    'quantity' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
                    'transamount' => string '20.0000' (length=7)
```

The aim is to get to total of all transaction grouped by the dates.

Comment: `$result = array_reduce($myArray, function($carry, $item) { return $carry + $item['quantity'] * $item['transamount']; }, 0.0);`

Comment: Thanks very much mark . It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This may not work since I'm not sure if you need to access the transactions using the date as a key... But something like this would add an element to each array item with the total.

```
// loop through the arrays sorted by date
foreach ($groups as $group)
{
    $total = 0;
    // loop through each transaction
    foreach ($group as $transaction)
    {
        // Add to the total for each purchase group
        $total += $transaction->quantity * $transaction->transamount;
    }
    // put the total into the group array
    $group->total = $total
}
```

With this you should end up with something like

```
'total' => (calculated value),     
'2017-7-03' =>
        array (size=3)
        0 =>
                array (size=4)
                'paydate' => string '2017-7-03' (length=9)
                'tariff' => string 'batch1' (length=31)
                'quantity' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
                'transamount' => string '20.0000' (length=7)
        1 =>
                array (size=4)
                'paydate' => string '2017-7-03' (length=9)
                'tariff' => string 'Eye Test' (length=8)
                'quantity' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
                'transamount' => string '5.0000' (length=6)
        2 =>
                array (size=4)
                'paydate' => string '2017-7-03' (length=9)
                'tariff' => string 'hub photos' (length=16)
                'quantity' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
                'transamount' => string '82.0000' (length=7)
                '2017-7-04' =>
```